# Not able to generate request object

Tags: python, get, httprequest

r = request.get(url='https://www.zomato.com')

It gives a time out error and python interpreter just does not respond . I have tried some other sites and it works for them , but for this site it does not . Why is that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, provide a [`User-Agent`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent) header may help a lot when trying to get a web page, which makes it more like a browser visit:

```
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.116 Safari/537.36 Edge/15.15063'
}

r = requests.get('https://www.zomato.com', headers=headers)
```